# after basic authentication redirect url modified

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, yii, url-rewriting

I have a site made using Yii framework. I have used HTTP authentication (basic) for user login purpose. It is working fine. And after authentication it redirects to user profile but in url after **www** part **https** is appended.eg. https://wwwhttps.example.com/directory/ I have also tried removing https part using .htaccess but no luck. Here is my .htaccess configuration:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks 
 IndexIgnore */*
 RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php 
 RewriteRule . index.php

#Basic ldap authentication goes here ...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wwwhttps\.(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

and the login controller code:

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        $this->layout='//layouts/login_layout';
        if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']) && $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']!='')
        {
            $username = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
            $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$username)); 

            $ui = UserIdentity::impersonate($user->id);
                if($ui)
                    Yii::app()->user->login($ui, 0);
                    $this->redirect(yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/user/profile');    
    }       
 }
```

Is it because of basic authentication or anything else? If I don't use basic authentication it works fine.... Please help me. 
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you please post the code related to login and after login, the functionality. so will be able to help you.

Comment: hi mazraara thanks for ur reply, i have edited my question adding login function too.

Comment: can you please remove the .htaccess file and try again. also whats ur output for echo yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/user/profile'; exit; ?

Comment: while removing ldap authentication code from htaccess file it works as expected. and output for yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) is eg. https://wwwhttps.example.com/directory/  https is appended with www part

Comment: yes, thats the problem then. htcaccess must be modified accordingly. update the question with your total contains of htaccess

Comment: @mazraara i have used this code in htaccess to remove https part from url:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wwwhttps\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]`
but redirect loop error is comming

Answer (score 2):

Change the .htaccess ldap authentication code to,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

So the entire htaccess will look like below,

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks 
 IndexIgnore */*
 RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php 
 RewriteRule . index.php

#Basic ldap authentication goes here ...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: nope i have tried it before not working https is still appended

Comment: with this code in place:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wwwhttps\.(.*)$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]`
it is redirecting to expected url but redirect loop error is showing

Comment: Can you please update the question including the error you received after this change.

Comment: This error normally comes, when there is an infinite loop of redirections. i.e index.php is redirecting to home.php, and then home.php is redirecting back to index.php, its an infinite loop..

Comment: yah i know that but i have checked there are no redirects like thata

Answer (score 2):

@Ronit Adhikari: There might be problem with environment variable. You should check that once.

Answer (score 2):

I got it right i have to set hostinfo and baseurl in main.php because my webroot is directory inside public folder:

```
request' => array(
                'hostInfo' => 'https://www.example.com',
                'baseUrl' => '/webroot',
           ),
```